PHPUnit is using the cached variable for multiple API call withing same function
When I'm calling same API multile time in PHPUnit test method, the second api call is using the first token instead of second.
If I separate these calls in different test methods, it is working fine.
Here is my test method
public function test_login()
{
    $user1 = User::factory()->create([ 'email' => $email1 = 'one@gmail.com' ]);
    $user2 = User::factory()->create(['email' => $email2 = 'two@gmail.com']);

    $tokens = [
        $user1->createToken('token_1', ['*'])->plainTextToken,
        $user2->createToken('token_2', ['*'])->plainTextToken,
    ];

    $response1 = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $tokens[0]])->getJson('api/user');

    // This response is ok
    $response1->dump();
    
    // This is suppose to return User 2 details, but returning user 1 details
    $response2 = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token[1]])->getJson('api/user');
    $response2->dump();
}

I've tried separating these API calls in different methods, which is working as expected.
I'm expecting how can I get user 2 details at second API calling.

"If I separate these calls in different test methods, it is working fine" That's because that's the ideal way of testing what you're trying to do. What specifically are you doing differently with your two users that warrants the second request? You should consider using a DataProvider to run through the different login scenarios you're after. This article also has some nice pointers.

what is this suppose to test? You could just do foreach ($tokens as $index => $token) {        $response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token])->getJson('api/user');        $response->assertOk();    }
If you want to be more assertive, do something like: ``` $this->assertNotEquals($tokens[0], $tokens[1], 'Tokens should be unique'); ` before the foreach to end the test immediately.
you want the details of 2 users, where is the asserts on the 'email'?

We have no idea what your controller is returning for this to happen, but it is not right to  test more than 1 API call on a test, you have to either use 2 tests, or a data provider as @maiorano84 mentioned, it is the standard way of doing it because it has a lot of advantages in doing so, especially that if your first call fails, the second one cannot be tested, the other way around, you can always test each one based on preconditions already set
